# Dúvida com a função fgets()

Tags: c, string

Estou com um problema com esse código. O primeiro produto é cadastrado normalmente, porém quando vou cadastrar o segundo produto o código pula para a linha de valor de compra do produto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Produtos{
   char nome[60];
   float precoCompra;
   float precoVenda;
   float lucro;
};

float Lucro(float venda, float compra){
    float lucro;

    lucro = venda - compra;
    lucro = (lucro / venda) * 100;

    return lucro;
}

int main(){
    struct Produtos produto[3];
    float lucro;
    int flag, aux = 0;
    int contlucro20 = 0, contlucro2030 = 0, contlucro30 = 0;

    while (flag != 0){

        //Cadastrando produtos:
        aux++;
        for(int i = 0; i < aux; i++){
            printf("\nProduto: "); fgets(produto[i].nome, 60, stdin);
            printf("\nPreco de Compra: "); scanf("%f", &produto[i].precoCompra);
            printf("\nPreco de Venda: "); scanf("%f", &produto[i].precoVenda);

            produto[i].lucro = Lucro(produto[i].precoVenda, produto[i].precoCompra);

            if (lucro < 20){contlucro20++;}
            else if (20 <= lucro && lucro <= 30){contlucro2030++;}
            else{contlucro30++;}

        }
        
        printf("\nDigite 0 para encerrar ou 1 para continuar: ");
        scanf("%d", &flag);
    }
    
    //Imprimindo lista de produtos:
    for(int i = 0; i < aux; i++){
        printf("\nProduto: %s", produto[i].nome);
        printf("\nPreco de Compra: %.2f", produto[i].precoCompra);
        printf("\nPreco de Venda: %.2f", produto[i].precoVenda);
        printf("\nLucro: %.2f%%\n", produto[i].lucro);
    }
   
    printf("\nNumero de produtos com lucro menor que 20%%: %d", contlucro20);
    printf("\nNumero de produtos com lucro entre  20%% e 30%%: %d", contlucro2030);
    printf("\nNumero de produtos com lucro maior que 30%%: %d", contlucro30);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: leia o manual: `scanf()` retorna um `int`. Teste. E consuma o `\n` que encerrou a leitura ou use outra função mais adequada para entrada, como `fgets()`

Comment: Não misture `fgets`/`gets` com `scanf`, [pode causar este tipo de problema](https://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html) <- este link também sugere algumas soluções

Answer (score -2):

Você está usando a função fgets na parte do codigo que você pede o nome do produto, essa função seve para ler os dados de um arquivo já criado, por isso não deu certo, você pode usar scanf("%s", produto[i].nome); para obter o nome do seu produto, e você também esqueceu de incluir a biblioteca stdio.h, fora isso seu código funciona, parabéns.

Comment: `fgets` não é só para ler de arquivos, também serve para dados digitados (é o que foi feito ali, está lendo do `stdin`). De qualquer forma, o problema todo é misturar `scanf` com `fgets`/`gets` ([leia aqui para mais detalhes](https://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html) <- este link também indica algumas soluções).

Comment: Não sabia que funcionava desse jeito também obrigado.